# Prove whether statement is true or false

Tags: logic, truth, proof

Consider the following:

> If a |= c or b |= c, then a ∨ b |= c. Prove whether this statement is true or false.

My gut instinct is to compare truth tables, but I don't think a truth table is possible with double turnstiles. Can someone offer me a better way to tackle this problem. I'm more interested in advice and hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question deals with **⊨** i.e. with [Logical consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence):

> A formula **A** is a logical consequence within some formal system of a set of statements **S** if and only if there is no model in which all members of **S** are true and **A** is false.

We can apply the definition above: by assumption, we have that every *truth valuation* that satisfy **a** will also satisfy **c** and every valuation that satisfy **b** will also satisfy **c**.

But a valuation that satisfy **a ∨ b** must satisfy either **a** or **b**.

Comment: Using what you said in the second paragraph. Since a ∨ b is true if either a or b is true or both. Then would this prove that a ∨ b entails c?

Comment: @Amous - Correct.

Answer (score -1):

This is false in general, as in the following example.

Let a = c = some false statement, and let b be some true statement. Then:

- (a |= c)    is true, therefore  ( a|=c  or  b|=c ) is also true.
- b is true, therefore  "a or b" is true.
- c is false.
- By the previous two points, ((a or b) |= c ) is false.

You can get the same result by analysing the formula 
"(( a -> c ) v ( b -> c )) -> ( a v b -> c )".

But if you assume that both a|=c AND b|=c hold,  then you can conclude that (a or b)|=c also holds.

Comment: Did you look at Mauro's answer? I think you're misreading the symbols.